# How to check if apscheduler is running in the background

Tags: python, apscheduler

I have a button that sends:

```
scheduler.start()
```

and would like to check whether it is running already to avoid *SchedulerAlreadyRunningError*

It seems simple enough but couldn't find a status flag in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was [this](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.running) not good enough?

Also, the `state` variable has been documented [here](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler).

Comment: Thanks, I missed it

Comment: How I would use it?
What I have:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def some_job():
    print("Decorated job")

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(some_job, 'interval', minutes=1)
scheduler.start()
```

So, after scheduler has started, I want to know if its up.
(My actual guess is that I will need to start scheduler in a separate thread to no-blocking my script and add after this something like: `scheduler.STATE_STOPPED`)

Comment: @Lukasavicus I think you need to ask this in a separate question.